# How to pass tcl array to perl command line argument

Tags: perl, tcl

I want to call the perl script from tcl in which i want to send tcl array to perl command line argument and how to use inside in perl script

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Tcl arrays are semantically similar to Perl hashes. You need to work out what serialization format you want to use. Tcl has a native one, but that's perhaps not the easiest for Perl to consume. Perhaps a JSON object would work? That's semantically right and both sides have suitable libraries. Also beware that big arrays/hashes may hit command line arguments; passing over a pipe may be better, or even doing the job properly and using a SQLite database…

Comment: Command-line arguments can only be strings. You will need to serialize the array somehow (e.g. using JSON) and deserialize it in the Perl program

Comment: Easiest way would to store data in a file, pass filename as an argument to perl script. You can use any format which can be stored and be read by tcl and perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Tcl array

```
array set ary {foo 11 bar 12 baz 13}
```

You can pass it to perl like this:

```
exec perl script.pl {*}[array get ary]
```

And in perl, you can say

```perl
my %hash = @ARGV;
```

Demonstrating (from a shell prompt):

```
$ echo '
  array set ary {foo "11 22" bar 12 baz 13}
  puts [exec perl -MData::Dump=dd -e {my %hash = @ARGV; dd \%hash} {*}[array get ary]]
' | tclsh
```

```
{ bar => 12, baz => 13, foo => "11 22" }
```

Comment: That's fine for small arrays (size depending on platform). For large arrays, send via a file or via a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

tcl :

```
set ax(0) 5
set ax(1) 6
set values ""

set names [array names ax]

  foreach xc $names {
    lappend values $ax($xc)
  }

exec perl path_to_perl_script.pl $names $values
```

perl:

```
 my @ar1 = split(" ", $ARGV[0]);
 my @ar2 = split(" ", $ARGV[1]);

 my %hash = ();
 my $length = @ar1;

   for (my $i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $hash{$ar1[$i]} = $ar2[$i];
   }

   foreach my $x (keys %hash) {
    print " $hash{$x}\n";
   }
```

output:
6
5